# Why doesn't this method get called?

Tags: oop, lua, love2d

I'm talking about `MovingGround:update()`. It doesn't crash; It just doesn't do anything that's in the method.

I did other things in the method. I set the player pos to 100 100 but that didn't happen so there's (probably) no error in the method itself—at least not that makes it do nothing. The method just doesnt get called!! I think the question is pretty much says the rest! Sooooo.... Here's the code!

-- Grounds

```
Ground = {}
Ground.__index = Ground

function Ground:new(x,y,width,height)
    grd = {}
    setmetatable(grd, Ground)
    grd.x = x
    grd.y = y
    grd.w = width
    grd.h = height
    grd.moving = false
    return grd
end

function Ground:draw(r,g,b)
    love.graphics.setColor(r,g,b)
    love.graphics.rectangle("line",self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h)
end

function Ground:update()
end

MovingGround = {}
MovingGround.__index = MovingGround

function MovingGround:new(x,y,w,h,spdx,spdy,stepsx,stepsy)
    grd = {}
    setmetatable(grd, Ground)
    grd.x = x
    grd.y = y
    grd.w = w
    grd.h = h
    grd.moving = true
    grd.spdx = spdx
    grd.spdy = spdy
    grd.stepsxmax = stepsx
    grd.stepsymax = stepsy
    grd.stepsx = 0
    grd.stepsy = 0
    grd.xdir = 1
    grd.ydir = 1
    return grd
end

function MovingGround:draw(r,g,b)
    love.graphics.setColor(r,g,b)
    love.graphics.rectangle("line",self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",300,self.y,self.w,self.h)
end

function MovingGround:update()
    if self.stepsx > self.stepsxmax or self.stepsx < 0 then self.spdx = -self.spdx self.dirx = -self.dirx end
    if self.stepsy > self.stepsymax or self.stepsy < 0 then self.spdy = -self.spdy self.diry = -self.diry end
    self.x = self.x + self.spdx
    self.y = self.y + self.spdy
    self.stepsx = self.stepsx + self.dirx
    self.stepsy = self.stepsy + self.diry
end
```

-- Main

```
require"functions"
require"player"
require"grounds"

grounds= {}
width = love.graphics.getWidth()
height = love.graphics.getHeight()

function love.load()
    test = Player:new(100,100,"w","a","s","d")
    grounds[5] = Ground:new(2,2,25,595) --links
    grounds[2] = Ground:new(2,2,795,25) --oben
    grounds[3] = Ground:new(772,2,25,595) --rechts
    grounds[4] = Ground:new(2,572,795,25) --unten
    grounds[1] = MovingGround:new(50,400,100,20,0,3,0,15)
end

function love.draw()
    test:draw(255,0,255)
    love.graphics.print("y : " .. tostring(test.y),10,10)
    love.graphics.print("x : " .. tostring(test.x),10,30)
    love.graphics.print(test.spdy,10,60)
    love.graphics.print(gd,10,90)
    love.graphics.print(1000 / gd,10,150)
    love.graphics.print(booltoString(test.onGround),10,120)
    love.graphics.print(grounds[1].stepsy,10,210)
    for i,v in ipairs(grounds) do
        grounds[i]:draw(255,255,255)
    end
end

function love.update(d)
    gd = d 
    test:update(d)
    for i,v in ipairs(grounds) do
        grounds[i]:update()
    end
end

function love.keypressed(key,code)
    if key == "space" then test:jump(-700) end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend using a debugger to determine the cause of this issue. Here's a walkthrough:

1. Find a place where the `update` method is being called on a `MovingGround` object and set a breakpoint there.
2. Run your program with debugging enabled, until it reaches the breakpoint.
3. Step into the call to the `update` method. What method do you end up getting taken to? Is it the method you were expecting?
4. Now that you're inside of the `update` method, look at the metatable of `self`. Is the metatable `MovingGround`?
5. The metatable was set inside of `MovingGround:new`, so set a breakpoint at the beginning of `MovingGround:new` and restart the program. Run until it reaches the breakpoint.
6. Step forward (using "step over", not "step into") until you see that the metatable of `grd` has been set as you saw in step 4.
7. Look at the line that you just stepped over. What needs to be changed?

Spoiler: in `MovingGround:new`, the metatable is getting set to `Ground` instead of `MovingGround`.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass in `dt` into any update function.

In this case, the function should be `MovingGround:update(dt)` (`ground.lua`) so that it updates every frame.

Similarly, in `main.lua` update function, the call should be `grounds[i]:update(dt)`.